# Knockout RadioButton List value changee,update in ListModel change

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

My problem :
 Radiobutton List with same name return key "on" in listModel:

Init List:

```
[{name:"one",selected:false},{name:"two",selected:false},...]
```

But  when i click radio button name "one", after that, click radiobutton "two":

```
[{name:"one",selected:"on"},{name:"two",selected:"on"},...]
```

I want data will:

```
[{name:"one",selected:false},{name:"two",selected:"on"},...]
```

OR

```
[{name:"one",selected:false},{name:"two",selected:true},...]
```

Work same as example : http://jsfiddle.net/DPnBE/5/

But i try this but not work:  http://jsfiddle.net/2L1m6d6a/2/

How can my code work as same as example! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your `items` property is an observable array but the example's one is a plain js array, so this code is not working:

```
var items = ko.contextFor(element).$parent.items; // items is an observable array
// observable array does not have a length property !!!
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    //set selected() for all items
    //true for the checked element, false for the rest
    items[i].selected(items[i] == item);                
}
```

You need to unwrap the observable array to acces the inner array:

```
var items = ko.contextFor(element).$parent.items(); // extra parens at the end
```